# why will my code not return false if the array is not descending or ascending order?

Tags: java

```
public class SmallestLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {3,6,2,1,23,6,7,54,3,2};
        System.out.println(isIncreasing(arr));

    }
    public static boolean isIncreasing(int[]arr)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > arr[i+1] || arr[i] < arr[i+1] )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
     }

    }
```

so if the array is int[] arr = {1,2,3} it should return true and if its descending order it should also be true anything else and it should return false, but my output is always true.

Comment: Because on your first check you return true it doesn't get to the end of the loop to return false.

Comment: what about `arr[0]` !??? Your for loop starts at 1..... also you're going to run into an out of bounds at some point with arr[i+1]

Answer (score 3):

If you will check if your Array is assending you have to Change your check:

```
public class SmallestLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {3,6,2,1,23,6,7,54,3,2};
        System.out.println(isIncreasing(arr));

    }
    public static boolean isIncreasing(int[]arr)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1;i++)
        {
            if( arr[i] > arr[i+1] )
                return false;
        }
        return true;
     }

    }
```

And your loop must end `at arr.length-1`
If not you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

And you have to start at 0, because Arrays in Java are Zero based.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as long as you have one value that is smaller than the other your code will return true. Your code should look like this.

```
public class SmallestLargest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arr = {3,6,2,1,23,6,7,54,3,2};
    System.out.println(isIncreasing(arr));

}
public static boolean isIncreasing(int[]arr)
{
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length - 1;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }

}
```

Comment: My answer was not like jens answer. The condition check was inversed in his.

Comment: {3,6,2,1,23,6,7,54,3,2}  comparing 3 < 6, continue looping, comparing 6 > 2 return false. if they are all < it will return true.

Comment: why do you subtract one from array.length?

Comment: Lets say we have 9 elements, when I reach the 9th one I don't want it to be compared with the 10th that doesn't exist. It will give me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

This will return true if the array is sorted - either ascending or descending. It can also handle flat sections of the array, where all entries are flat, one entry and no entries.

It is debatable whether an empty array is sorted.

```
public enum Direction {

    Descending {

                @Override
                boolean is(int a, int b) {
                    return b <= a;
                }
            },
    Ascending {
                @Override
                boolean is(int a, int b) {
                    return a <= b;
                }
            };

    abstract boolean is(int a, int b);
}

public static boolean isSorted(int[] n) {
    // All possible directions.
    Set<Direction> possibles = EnumSet.<Direction>allOf(Direction.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length - 1 && possibles.size() > 0; i++) {
        // Check all currently possible directions.
        for (Iterator<Direction> it = possibles.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Direction d = it.next();
            if (!d.is(n[i], n[i + 1])) {
                // Not in that direction.
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    return possibles.size() > 0;
}

public void test(int[] arr) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr) + " is " + (!isSorted(arr) ? "not " : "") + "sorted");
}

public void test() {
    test(new int[]{3, 6, 2, 1, 23, 6, 7, 54, 3, 2});
    test(new int[]{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
    test(new int[]{3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9});
    test(new int[]{4, 4, 4, 4});
    test(new int[]{1});
    test(new int[]{});
    test(new int[]{100, 50, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1});
}
```

Comment: Isn't it overkill to create enums for deciding the sort order? I would simply go with creating two separate methods rather.

Comment: @RohitJain - Two separate methods would be less efficient IMHO. It's not overkill to do it right. This mechanism would cover many other patterns.

Comment: I was not even talking about efficiency, but since you've started, I don't see how two methods would be less efficient. You'll still be going over your array twice - once each for increasing and decreasing order. That you are already doing. Talking about many other patterns - I would say, early generalization, just like early optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @RohitJain - I may be performing two comparisons but I am only walking the array once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
boolean status=false;
public static boolean isIncreasing(int[]arr)
{
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1] || arr[i] < arr[i+1] )
            status=true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```